# How to read iOS in app purchase receipt

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewable

I'm able to read the receipts for in app purchase(in sandbox). I want to validate them for auto renewable subscription. But problem is that when I read the receipt I got the same date for *purchase_date* and *expires_date*. Below is response which I got:

```
{
    "expires_date" = "2018-03-26 09:34:11 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_ms" = 1522056851000;
    "expires_date_pst" = "2018-03-26 02:34:11 America/Los_Angeles";
    "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
    "is_trial_period" = false;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2018-03-26 09:29:15 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1522056555000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2018-03-26 02:29:15 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000385357059343435656;
    "product_id" = <product id>;
    "purchase_date" = "2018-03-26 09:29:11 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1522056551000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2018-03-26 02:29:11 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 1000000385357059343435656;
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000385357059343435656;
}
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

PS: Subscription is for one month and I purchased this today (i.e.26March18). So I think *expires_date* should be 22April2018.

Comment: Everything is correct: in sandbox durations are different, see docs https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev7e89e149d

Comment: @kambala hey thanks you are correct, please post it as answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct: in Sandbox durations are different, so instead of 1 month you receive 5 minutes. See official docs for details: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev7e89e149d

Also, like @jaba-odishelashvili pointed out, you should use different URLs for verification of Sandbox/Production receipt.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt url to verify receipt.

Here is sample code you can use:

```
NSString *appStoreReceiptPath = NSBundle.mainBundle.appStoreReceiptURL.path;
if(appStoreReceiptPath) {
    NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:appStoreReceiptPath];
    if(receiptData == nil) return;
    NSDictionary *receiptDictionary = @{@"receipt-data": [receiptData base64Encoding],
                                        @"password": SharedSecret};

    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:receiptDictionary options:0 error:nil];
    // ReceiptURL is - @"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ReceiptURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:storeURL];
    storeRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    storeRequest.HTTPBody = requestData;

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:storeRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

            if(!jsonError) {
                for(NSDictionary *in_app in dictionary[@"receipt"][@"in_app"]) {
                    NSString *purchaseDateString = in_app[@"purchase_date"];
                    NSString *expiresDateString = in_app[@"expires_date"];

                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"];

                    NSString *productId = in_app[@"product_id"];
                    NSString *purchaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:purchaseDateString];
                    NSString *expiresDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:expiresDateString];


                }
            }
        }
    }] resume];
}
```

and use this method to detect if subscription is active or not.

```
- (BOOL) isActiveSubscriptionBought:(NSDate *) purchaseDate expires:(NSDate*) expiresDate  {
    if(self.expiresDate == nil) return false;

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    return (([date compare:purchaseDate] != NSOrderedAscending) &&
            ([date compare:expiresDate] != NSOrderedDescending));
}
```